# SSJS MC Attributes.Retrieve() doesn't return EmailAddress

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, subscriber-key

isn't EmailAddress one of the Subscriber's attributes? How to fetch it from All Subscribers list (or Subscriber Object) using SSJS with SubscriberKey? Could it be blocked on the parent lvl?

Piece of the code:

```
var subscriber = Subscriber.Init(subscriberKey);
var attributes = subscriber.Attributes.Retrieve();
```

returns an array: `[{"Name":"Salutation","Value":""}, {"Name":"First Name","Value":"Alex"}, {"Name":"Last Name","Value":""}, {"Name":"VWProfileID","Value":""}, {"Name":"Geburtsdatum","Value":""}, {"Name":"id","Value":""}, {"Name":"sfCampaignId","Value":""}, {"Name":"sfCampaignMemberId","Value":""}]` with no EmailAddress attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmailAddress indeed is not an attribute, it is a property directly on the subscriber object.
Makes sense too, Profile Attributes are things that you configure, whereas EmailAddress is on the subscriber object by default, like SubscriberKey itself, or Status.

Please see here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/subscriber.html#properties

> Attributes | Attribute[] |Specifies attributes associated with an object.

vs.

> EmailAddress |    xsd | Contains the email address for a subscriber. Indicates the data extension field contains email address data.

meaning that you get it like so (alongside subscriberkey and status):

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server"> 
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var subscriberKey = "mySubscriberKey"
var subResult = Subscriber.Retrieve({Property:"SubscriberKey",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:subscriberKey});
email = subResult[0].EmailAddress
subscriberKeyResult = subResult[0].SubscriberKey
status = subResult[0].Status
Write(email + " /// ");
Write(subscriberKeyResult+ " /// ");
Write(status);
</script>
```

result:

```
myEmailaddress@example.com /// mySubscriberKey /// Active
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: no worries, please mark the answer as accepted if this solved your problem.cheers